# How to select a row with differents values in MYSQL?

Tags: mysql, sql

```
---------------
|ID |X | Y     |
---------------
|1  |A | True  |
|2  |B | False |
|3  |B | False |
|4  |A | False |
|5  |C | True  |
----------------
```

I want to know how to `SELECT` just X who has different Y.

In my example I want to `SELECT` A. I don't want to `SELECT` B and C. I'm looking for a simple sql query.

Comment: what do you mean by SELECT just X who has different Y?

Comment: I dont know how to do it in sql language. Select X FROM table WHERE x = 'True' AND x = 'False'

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Do a `GROUP BY`. Use `HAVING` to make sure there are at least 2 different y values.

```
select x
from tablename
group by x
having count(distinct y) > 1
```